# Exception when trying to update twitter status using java

Tags: java, twitter

I'm trying to update status using java with this lib : https://code.google.com/p/java-twitter/ .

and this code :

```
Api api = Api.builder().username("username").password("password").build();
api.updateStatus("Just test").build().post();
```

but when i run the application this exception occurs :

```
exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/protobuf/Descriptors$FileDescriptor$InternalDescriptorAssigner
    at net.unto.twitter.UtilProtos$Url$Scheme.<clinit>(UtilProtos.java:83)
    at net.unto.twitter.Api.<clinit>(Api.java:97)
```

any help ?

and what is the simplest way to post tweets from java ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you grabbed the full ProtoBuf library and put it on the classpath?

Comment: I just download the java-twitter-0.9-SNAPSHOT.jar and add it to the classpath

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the protobuf libraries. Download them from [here](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/downloads/list) and put that in your classpath as well.

Comment: I download it but another exception come ! Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$FileDescriptor.internalBuildGeneratedFileFrom(Ljava/lang/String;[Lcom/google/protobuf/Descriptors$FileDescriptor;Lcom/google/protobuf/Descriptors$FileDescriptor$InternalDescriptorAssigner;)V
 at net.unto.twitter.UtilProtos.<clinit>(UtilProtos.java:598)
 at net.unto.twitter.UtilProtos$Url$Scheme.<clinit>(UtilProtos.java:83)
 at net.unto.twitter.Api.<clinit>(Api.java:97)

Comment: @user2728312 First of all, no need to exclaim. Second, why can't you edit your original post where the stacktrace is actually *readable*?

Answer (score 0):

Simply downloading the java-twitter jar and adding it to your classpath is not enough.
The library has runtime dependencies. a list of which is available on the project page, [link](https://code.google.com/p/java-twitter/#Runtime_Dependencies).

You need to make sure you have all the runtime dependencies on the classpath so that you will be able to use the library.